# The distributive law in a square

Tags: tables, color, rules

I am trying to do the following but I am not sure how to go about it. Should I just go with a table and make the lines thicker? I am also trying to make the lines around the box blue and thicker. Can I automate it?

[image]

I have started with this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\newcounter{example}
\counterwithin*{example}{section}
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{%
\stepcounter{example}%
\par\vspace{5pt}\noindent
\fbox{\textbf{Example~\theexample}}%
\hrulefill\par\vspace{10pt}\noindent\rmfamily}%
{\par\noindent\hrulefill\vrule width10pt height2pt depth2pt\par}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}

\begin{example}
    \begin{tasks}
        \task $(x+2)(x+3)$
    \end{tasks}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: My apologies for the confusion. My document is something like this. I attempted to simplify it but have made it more confusing.

```
\documentclass[
  a5paper,
  % pagesize,11pt,% both are default and therefore not needed
  bibliography=totoc,% bibtotoc is deprecated and therefore replaced according
                     % to the warning message
  numbers=noenddot,% pointlessnumbers is deprecated and therefore replaced
                   % according to the warning message
  headings=normal,% normalheadings is deprecated and therefore replaced
                  % according to the warning message
  DIV=9,twoside=false,
  headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,% see the KOMA-Script manual
headheight=87pt,% not used, to not lower the header, but this results in a warning
footheight=52pt, % no longer needed, because the lines are not part of the footer
]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\usepackage{trajan}

\usepackage{setspace}

\linespread{1.05}

\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}% moved according to the KOMA-Script manual, because it
                      % makes no sense before changing font an linespread.

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[%
  autoenlargeheadfoot=false,% only warn but don't change height reserved for header or footer  
  manualmark,% or maybe automark, this is not clear due to missing information
             % in the question.
  plainheadsepline,plainfootsepline,% See the KOMA-Script manual for more information
  ]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a5paper,
 total={100mm,200mm}, %not sue what this line is either.
 left=15mm,
 right=15mm,
 top=30mm,
 bottom=35mm,
 headsep=2mm,
 }

 \usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{multicol,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}

\newcommand*{\answerline}[1][4cm]{\rule{0pt}{1cm}\rule{#1}{0.1mm}}

\usepackage{cancel}

\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage[table]

\newcounter{example}[section]
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{%
   \setlength\fboxrule{1pt}
   \refstepcounter{example}
   \par\vspace{5pt}\noindent
   \fcolorbox{blue}{white}{\textbf{Example~\theexample}}%
   \textcolor{blue}{\hrulefill}
   \par\vspace{10pt}\noindent\rmfamily}%
  {\par\noindent\color{blue}\hrulefill
    \vrule width10pt height2pt depth2pt\par}


 \begin{document}

 \begin{example}
    \begin{tasks}
        \task $(x+2)(x+3)$
    \end{tasks}    
    \Large
    \[
       \mysquare{x}{2}{x}{x^2}{2x}{3}{3x}{6}
    \]
\end{example}
 
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `efbox` works well for simple boxes with coloured lines etc. Or `tcolorbox` will give you all the bells and whistles at the price of a heavier package. But if you use `tikz` or something anyway, it might still make sense. Please don't add irrelevant tags. Overleaf is just your editor: it doesn't have anything to do with the question.

Comment: In your augmented code example, is `\usepackage[table]` supposed to say `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There many ways to do this with more and less sophisticated packages and more and less complex custom configuration. Here's an example using `efbox`, `makecell` and `xcolor`.

If you want to typeset many examples with a similar format, you can create a custom macro or environment to avoid duplicating code. You can also use the configuration commands provided by `efbox` and/or `makecell`. I've shown an example here where the alignment of table headings is configured globally, but this may or may not be even part of what makes most sense in your situation.

Regardless of other considerations, I'd recommend using `\efboxsetup{}` to configure standard settings and to do something similar for `makecell` in order to ensure consistency and enable ease of alterations to formatting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{efbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tasks}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\newcounter{example}
\counterwithin*{example}{section}
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{%
  \stepcounter{example}%
  \par\vspace{5pt}\noindent
  \efbox[font=\normalfont\bfseries,linecolor=cyan,linewidth=.6pt]{Example~\theexample}%
  {\color{cyan}\hrulefill}\par\vspace{10pt}\noindent\rmfamily}%
{\par\noindent{\color{cyan}\hrulefill\vrule width10pt height2pt depth2pt}\par}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\color{black}}c}
\renewcommand\theadalign{CCC}
\begin{document}

\begin{example}
\begin{tasks}
  \task $(x+2)(x+3)$
  \begin{center}
    \color{red}
    \begin{tabular}{%
        *{3}{!{\vrule width 1pt}C}!{\vrule width 1pt}
      }
      \Xcline{2-3}{1pt}
      \multicolumn{1}{c!{\vrule width 1pt}}{\thead{$\times$}} & \thead{$x$} & \thead{$2$} \\\Xhline{1pt}
      \thead{$x$} & $x^{2}$ & $2x$ \\\Xhline{1pt}
      \thead{$3$} & $3x$ &  $6$ \\\Xhline{1pt}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{tasks}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

The above code produces output very similar to the target image with `cyan` highlighting the task and `red` highlighting the answer. `makecell` enables gappier cells in the `tabular` and standard configuration for headings etc.

*From community:*
[image]

### Edit

To respond to the followup question in the comment, you can adjust the width of the lines by replacing `\hrulefill` with a suitable `\vrule`. For this, we create some variables to hold lengths and a box so we can measure the `\efbox` without typesetting it twice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{efbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tasks}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\newcounter{example}
\counterwithin*{example}{section}
\newlength \templgtha
\newlength \templgthb
\newlength \templgthc
\newsavebox \tempboxa
\setlength \templgthb {\textwidth}
\setlength \templgthc {\textwidth}
\addtolength \templgthc {-10pt}
\newenvironment{example}{%
  \stepcounter{example}%
  \par\vspace{5pt}\noindent
  \sbox \tempboxa{%
    \efbox[font=\normalfont\bfseries,linecolor=cyan,linewidth=.6pt]{Example~\theexample}%
  }%
  \settowidth \templgtha {\usebox \tempboxa}%
  \addtolength \templgthb {-\templgtha}%
  \usebox \tempboxa
  {\color{cyan}\vrule width\templgthb height0.3pt depth0.3pt}\par\vspace{10pt}\noindent\rmfamily
}{%
  \par\noindent
  {%
    \color{cyan}%
    \vrule width\templgthc height0.3pt depth0.3pt
    \vrule width10pt height2pt depth2pt
  }\par
}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\color{black}}c}
\renewcommand\theadalign{CCC}
\begin{document}

\begin{example}
  \begin{tasks}
    \task $(x+2)(x+3)$
    \begin{center}
      \color{red}
      \begin{tabular}{%
          *{3}{!{\vrule width 1pt}C}!{\vrule width 1pt}
        }
        \Xcline{2-3}{1pt}
        \multicolumn{1}{c!{\vrule width 1pt}}{\thead{$\times$}} & \thead{$x$} & \thead{$2$} \\\Xhline{1pt}
        \thead{$x$} & $x^{2}$ & $2x$ \\\Xhline{1pt}
        \thead{$3$} & $3x$ &  $6$ \\\Xhline{1pt}
      \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
  \end{tasks}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

The output looks just like the image above except that the horizontal cyan rules are now `0.6pt` (`0.3pt` + `0.3pt`) in width rather than using the default line width. This matches the width of the rules used for the `\efbox` and should probably be adjusted in sync with those settings. That is, if you use `0.8pt` for the box, you probably want `0.4pt` for the height and depth of the rule etc.

Comment: Hello, thank you so. much. How would I make the horizontal lines thicker?

Comment: @user292225 Please see edit. Sorry about taxing your imagination. Okular has a bug which makes my images so poor when I tried to copy a line yesterday you couldn't even see there was a line - never mind that it looked different!

Comment: @user292225 You can combine that adjustment with Mico's answer for a more automated approach. (Though I probably wouldn't go for a `\newcommand` with 8 arguments if I could avoid it. Then again, it isn't so bad in this case as the table gives the order ....)

Comment: I am very grateful for this. Thank you. This is going to sound terrible and of course something I should've thought about. The page I am using is A5 and when I use this code, the example lines don't extend to my page margins. So sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @user292225 Should be fixed now. I shouldn't have used `\linewidth`. I think `tasks` alters it. Anyway, `\textwidth` works. Are you using `geometry`? It behaves very oddly with `a5paper` and everything else default.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcounter{example}[section]
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{%
   \setlength\fboxrule{1pt}
   \refstepcounter{example}
   \par\vspace{5pt}\noindent
   \fcolorbox{blue}{white}{\textbf{Example~\theexample}}%
   \textcolor{blue}{\hrulefill}
   \par\vspace{10pt}\noindent\rmfamily}%
  {\par\noindent\color{blue}\hrulefill
    \vrule width10pt height2pt depth2pt\par}

\newcommand\mysquare[8]{%
  \arrayrulecolor{red}
  \setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt} % set line thickness
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
  \begin{array}{|*{3}{wc{1cm}|}} % fixed-width columns
     \cline{2-3}
     \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\times} & #1 & #2 \\
     \hline
     #3 & #4 & #5 \\
     \hline
     #6 & #7 & #8 \\
     \hline
  \end{array}}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
    \begin{tasks}
        \task $(x+2)(x+3)$
    \end{tasks}    
    \Large
    \[
       \mysquare{x}{2}{x}{x^2}{2x}{3}{3x}{6}
    \]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, THank you so much for this. I am wondering how I would set the thickness of the lines extending from the example part. Also, if I wanted to learn more about 'automating', what would you reccomend?

Comment: Can I make the width of the right column and the bottom column bigger/different?

Comment: @user292225 Do you mean the bottom row?

Comment: For example, I want to make the one with two in it longer to the right and the one with 3 in it longer as well.

Comment: @user292225 - I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by either "make the one with two in it longer to the right" or "[make] the one with 3 in it longer". Please clarify.